# Set different payment method for Azure pay-as-you-go subscriptions

Tags: azure, billing, azure-billing

In the Azure portal I have added two different credit cards. One of them is set as Default.

I have several pay-as-you-go subscriptions. All of them show the "Default payment method" and I can't find any way to specify the payment method per subscription. Should this be possible?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing support question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Set different payment method for Azure pay-as-you-go subscriptions:**

Please follow the steps to change the payment method.

**Azure Portal > Subscription > Payment Methods > Add payment method.**

[image]

If you have 2 or more payment methods in single subscription, to make it as default payment method, Select **make default** option.

[image]

Reference: [Add, update, or delete a payment method - Microsoft Cost Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-credit-card#replace-credit-card-for-a-subscription-to-a-previously-saved-credit-card)

Comment: The texts in the UI were very confusing because when changing the default payment method for one subscription it says "This will also update other Azure subscriptions using the current default payment method." But apparently it only changed the default payment method for one subscription.